# Is it awkward to use the verb "to mint" with "law"?

Tags: word-usage

Would it be awkward to use the verb "to mint" with "law" ?

For instance: "Minted in 1962, this law ..."

Comment: Not a common collocation. [Ngrams for "mint law" and "pass law"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mint+law%2C+hammer+out+law%2C+pass+law&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmint%20law%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmint%20law%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMint%20Law%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMint%20law%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cpass%20law%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpass%20law%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPass%20Law%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPass%20law%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bpass%20Law%3B%2Cc0) show that mint + law is rarely used; when found together it is usually a matter of coincidence. Please check in GR.

Comment: It would be uncommon.

Comment: Laws are passed or enacted or legislated. Coins are minted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Crafted**.

It would be poetic. It suggests the law being carefully designed, new, fresh, valuable, and possibly, beautiful, like a new coin. It is not a common use.

Alternatively you could say ‘struck in 1962, this law...’ (also poetic, still referring to coins, which are ‘struck’ when first minted).

You could say ‘crafted in 1962, this law...’ if you are praising it.

Craft is ‘skill in making, creating, or executing’

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/craft

Comment: To me, a law struck is a law abolished.